# `man` pages for languages other than C (e.g, python, R, javascript, etc)?

Tags: python, man, documentation, programming, standard

`man` pages are a phenomenal resource while programming in C on Linux.  While looking at someone else's code, if you see something foreign you can immediate research it in another terminal with

```
$ man 3 fileno
```

or whatever the syntax you don't understand is.

Is there a standard way to get "`man`" pages for other programming languages like Python, R, Javascript, or anything else?  It doesn't actually have to be `man`, but some program I can quickly call to research something like

```
$ man-python numpy.random.rand
```

instead of having to Google it and use HTML documentation.  The same question holds generally for other programming languages.

Comment: At least python has the `pydoc`, `pydoc2`, `pydoc3` tools for viewing information. However, they do not process RST markup in the docstrings. IIRC Perl and Tcl also contain information in the form of man pages.

Comment: Great question... I'd love if I had man pages for JavaScript and NodeJS :(

Comment: @n2liquid-GuilhermeVieira, if you use [ddg.gg](http://ddg.gg) as a search engine, I have found other languages basically work like man pages with bang syntax (e.g., type [`!php get_headers`](http://ddg.gg/?q=!php+get_headers) to get the PHP documentation).  Unfortunately, `!js` leads to the MDN documentation, which is horribly unsearchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not reliably (or portably); on OpenBSD `man -s ...` lets you search by section, though outside of system or C related things, there are only sections for Fortran, Perl, and Tcl/Tk. Still, a search for say `strftime` in the Perl section will not find anything, as that call is hiding inside `POSIX` (or various other modules), and will not appear anywhere a `man -k` search can find it.

```
% man -k -s 3p strftime
% man -k -s 3p POSIX   
locale(3p) - Perl pragma to use or avoid POSIX locales for built-in operations
POSIX(3p) - Perl interface to IEEE Std 1003.1
%
```

Meanwhile, `man` over on Mac OS X lacks `-s`, and the quality and quantity of the man pages is quite poor (missing, or a random pilfering from some vintage of (Free|Open|Net)BSD). Linux likewise has a dubious record of man page maintenance ("see the `info` page, lol!", etc).

In theory the manual pages could have been a well-maintained resource, and in theory there could be searchable sections for R or other such languages, but that's generally not what happened.

Comment: I didn't use this answer, but since you were the only one nice enough to reply I marked as solved.  Thanks.